# How to create points at line meeting points in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geometry

I have some countinous multilines(with 1 or more common points), and i would like to create points at the common points.
I tried with starting point and ending point creation, but it doesn't end or start at the wanted point.

Any idea?
[image: One feature is selected here]

Comment: Can you switch your picture to some simpler geometries (e.g. two lines with just 3 vertices each)?  That way you can label each vertex in the picture to describe what should happen to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) with `output_type=POINT`

> POINT —Point intersections will be returned. If the inputs are line or
> polygon, the output will be a multipoint feature class.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about, that there is an output type in this tool.